# Jeep Grand Cherokee 1996 limited model - lack of power while sudden accelerating

Tags: jeep, rough-idle, grand-cherokee, power-loss

Hi I have Jeep Grand Cherokee 1996 limited model - the problem is engine misfire in idle while cold starting and engine stady (not fully stady) after become hot, and  lack of power while we accelerat suddenly.can not drive the vehicle.

I have clean all the fuel injectors, change all spark plugs, fuel pump is new, clean distridutor cap and rotor , check spark plug wire, IAC motor, throttle positon sensor, vaccume lines all found ok , check fault codes found no fault code.

So please advice further.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm sure it's a language difference, but I'm unsure what "stady" means? If there aren't any fault codes, how do you know it's a misfire? A misfire should show with the CEL and a code as this is pretty easy for the computer to detect.